# Using C# code in Powershell scripts and Save results in variable

Tags: c#, powershell

I'm using C# code in Powershell:

```
$Code = @'
....................
public class RDPInfo
....................
'@
Add-Type $Code
$ListUsers = [RDPInfo]::ListUsers("ServerName")
$ListUsers -eq $null
```

The script works and returns result - list of users on server (must be array, I think), but cannot save to variable `$ListUsers` - it is left empty. Can you advise how to deal with it? 
Thanks.

P.S. Here is a full code:

```
# QuerySessionInformation.ps1
# Written by Ryan Ries, Jan. 2013, with help from MSDN and Stackoverflow.

$Code = @'
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
public class RDPInfo
{
    [DllImport("wtsapi32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr WTSOpenServer([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] String pServerName);

    [DllImport("wtsapi32.dll")]
    static extern void WTSCloseServer(IntPtr hServer);

    [DllImport("wtsapi32.dll")]
    static extern Int32 WTSEnumerateSessions(
        IntPtr hServer,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] Int32 Reserved,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] Int32 Version,
        ref IntPtr ppSessionInfo,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] ref Int32 pCount);

    [DllImport("wtsapi32.dll")]
    static extern void WTSFreeMemory(IntPtr pMemory);

    [DllImport("Wtsapi32.dll")]
    static extern bool WTSQuerySessionInformation(System.IntPtr hServer, int sessionId, WTS_INFO_CLASS wtsInfoClass, out System.IntPtr ppBuffer, out uint pBytesReturned);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct WTS_SESSION_INFO
    {
        public Int32 SessionID;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
        public String pWinStationName;
        public WTS_CONNECTSTATE_CLASS State;
    }

    public enum WTS_INFO_CLASS
    {
        WTSInitialProgram,
        WTSApplicationName,
        WTSWorkingDirectory,
        WTSOEMId,
        WTSSessionId,
        WTSUserName,
        WTSWinStationName,
        WTSDomainName,
        WTSConnectState,
        WTSClientBuildNumber,
        WTSClientName,
        WTSClientDirectory,
        WTSClientProductId,
        WTSClientHardwareId,
        WTSClientAddress,
        WTSClientDisplay,
        WTSClientProtocolType
    }

    public enum WTS_CONNECTSTATE_CLASS
    {
        WTSActive,
        WTSConnected,
        WTSConnectQuery,
        WTSShadow,
        WTSDisconnected,
        WTSIdle,
        WTSListen,
        WTSReset,
        WTSDown,
        WTSInit
    }

    public static IntPtr OpenServer(String Name)
    {
        IntPtr server = WTSOpenServer(Name);
        return server;
    }

    public static void CloseServer(IntPtr ServerHandle)
    {
        WTSCloseServer(ServerHandle);
    }

    public static void ListUsers(String ServerName)
    {
        IntPtr serverHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
        List<String> resultList = new List<string>();
        serverHandle = OpenServer(ServerName);

        try
        {
            IntPtr SessionInfoPtr = IntPtr.Zero;
            IntPtr userPtr = IntPtr.Zero;
            IntPtr domainPtr = IntPtr.Zero;
            IntPtr clientNamePtr = IntPtr.Zero;
            Int32 sessionCount = 0;
            Int32 retVal = WTSEnumerateSessions(serverHandle, 0, 1, ref SessionInfoPtr, ref sessionCount);
            Int32 dataSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(WTS_SESSION_INFO));
            Int32 currentSession = (int)SessionInfoPtr;
            uint bytes = 0;
            if (retVal != 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < sessionCount; i++)
                {
                    WTS_SESSION_INFO si = (WTS_SESSION_INFO)Marshal.PtrToStructure((System.IntPtr)currentSession, typeof(WTS_SESSION_INFO));
                    currentSession += dataSize;

                    WTSQuerySessionInformation(serverHandle, si.SessionID, WTS_INFO_CLASS.WTSUserName, out userPtr, out bytes);
                    WTSQuerySessionInformation(serverHandle, si.SessionID, WTS_INFO_CLASS.WTSDomainName, out domainPtr, out bytes);
                    WTSQuerySessionInformation(serverHandle, si.SessionID, WTS_INFO_CLASS.WTSClientName, out clientNamePtr, out bytes);

                   if(Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(domainPtr).Length > 0 && Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(userPtr).Length > 0)
                    {
                        if(Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(clientNamePtr).Length < 1)                       
                            /* Console.WriteLine(Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(domainPtr) + "\\" + Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(userPtr) + "\tSessionID: " + si.SessionID + "\tClientName: n/a");   */
                            Console.WriteLine(Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(userPtr));
                        else
                            /* Console.WriteLine(Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(domainPtr) + "\\" + Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(userPtr) + "\tSessionID: " + si.SessionID + "\tClientName: " + Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(clientNamePtr));   */
                            Console.WriteLine(Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(userPtr));
                    }
                    WTSFreeMemory(clientNamePtr);
                    WTSFreeMemory(userPtr);
                    WTSFreeMemory(domainPtr);
                }
                WTSFreeMemory(SessionInfoPtr);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            CloseServer(serverHandle);
        }
    }
}
'@

Add-Type $Code
$ListUsers = [RDPInfo]::ListUsers("SERVERNAME")
$ListUsers -eq $null #TRUE
```

Gives result:

```
Username1
Username2
.........
UsernameN
ListUsers :
```

But $ListUsers variable is empty!

Comment: Really hard to help you without seeing c# code. Actually seems that in the code  there's something like `$a = write-host "something"` ... `$a` remains empty.

Comment: `RDPInfo` probably uses `Console.WriteLine()` or similar functionality to output the results

Comment: I've added a full code above. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, there Mathias R. Jessen, there is `Console.WriteLine()` inside `C# `code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your function *public static void ListUsers(String ServerName)* to

```
public static List<string> ListUsers(String ServerName)
```

In the for loop add the username to your list:

```
resultList.Add(Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(userPtr));
```

At the end of the function return the list:

```
return resultList;
```

This should do it...

Comment: Awesome, Norman. Thanks you a lot. It works!!! Now I'm understand, code didn't return some value, just `Console.Writeline()` it.